# How do you quit without saving when using vim -c flag

Tags: vim

I want to run something along the lines of

```
vim -r -c "w %.new | q!" ${filename}
```

However, the ! is parsed as the prefix for an external command.  Similar issues happen when using single quotes.

I could work around this with the following code, but it feels much less clean or obvious than the previous code.

```
cp ${filename} ${filename}.new && mv .${filename}.swp .${filename}.new.swp;
vim -r -c "wq" ${filename}.new;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes. The `!` is being interpreted in bash not vim.

```
vim -r -c 'w %.new | q!' ${filename}
```

`!` followed by test runs the last command that starts with that text. In this case bash looks for a command starting with `"` which isn't found. The single quotes stops bash from interpreting the `!`

[Some examples](http://ss64.com/bash/bang.html) of using `!` in bash

It seems the actual problem was that `%.new` existed. To just force over write use `w!` instead of `w`

```
vim -r -c 'w! %.new | q!' ${filename}
```

Comment: Ah, thought I'd tried that.  I wasn't paying enough attention to the error.  Was erroring on the write to %.new because it existed.  Changing to

    w! %.new

fixes that obviously.